# How can i create Google Maps API key (Maps, Routes, Places)?

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I own a website which is a business listing service. But the Google Maps aren't showing. Even though i created an API, which my wordpress themes

Answer (score 1):

In order to create an api key, you should to go https://console.developers.google.com/getting-started and log in with your account.

Create a new project and proceed to activate the APIs you need.

Comment: I did, but that API is getting error on my Wordpress website.

Comment: Please share the error/s and the activated APIs in your account

Comment: https://imgur.com/zvtCjWG https://imgur.com/E6arH3y

Comment: As per the error decription it seems the Maps JavaScript API has not been authorized for the used API key.  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages

Comment: In the api console, you putted the authorised URLs??

Comment: Inside credentials, you can config the authorised URLs or IPs

Comment: Can you tell me where to add Authorised URLs in API console?

Comment: Of course! In the Api console, open the Credential option (left menu), under Application restrictions select HTTP Referers (websites), in the right side will apear how to introduce the url or urls. I hope mi contribution will helps you!

Comment: Hi, with your help i am managed to fix it. But there is a small problem, i am getting "For Development Purpose Only" https://imgur.com/EDsP1JG

Any idea how can i fix it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110605/discussion-between-benetj-and-fahad-ur-rehman-khan).